# adding PATHs for a bunch of programs

Tags: path

I have a big list of programs (samtools,annovar,bra,bedtools etc) in a "Programs" folder.

I have read lots of posts about exporting the path, so that I do not need to identify the whole path to the program from my working folder. However, it still does not work, I guess because I am mixing everything.

There is a perl script in the folder variant_effect_predictor which I want to assess from another folders without typing the whole path to this script.

I am working on OS X. I added to my `~/.profile` following:

```
export PATH=/Users/pics/Desktop/MyDocuments/Programms/ensembl-tools-release-78/scripts/variant_effect_predictor:$PATH
```

somehow it tells me:

```
pik:Annotation pic$ perl variant_effect_predictor.pl -custom C0066PH1.H3K4me1.ppqt_macs2_broad_v2.20130819.bed.gz,BED_annotation,BED,overlap,1 -i SNPs_vep_input.txt --cache --force_overwrite --symbol 
Can't open perl script "variant_effect_predictor.pl": No such file or directory
```

So, the path was not exported or added. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it as `perl variant_effect_predictor.pl` you're telling the `perl` executable that a script called `variant_effect_predictor.pl` is located in the current directory and to run it.

If it's executable (`chmod +x /Users/pics/Desktop/MyDocuments/Programms/ensembl-tools-release-78/scripts/variant_effect_predictor/variant_effect_predictor.pl`) and the inside of the script starts with a shebang ("`#!/usr/bin/perl`" or similar on the first line) you should be able to leave the `perl` part off the begining of the command which will then cause `bash` to search `$PATH` which is what you're wanting.

Answer (score 1):

As Bratchley already wrote, you can leave out the "perl" part of your command if your perl script is executable and has the right shebang line.

Alternatively, you can use the `-S`command line option for perl to let it search for the `variant_effect_predictor.pl` in your PATH:

> -S
>
> makes Perl use the PATH environment variable to search for the program
>   unless the name of the program contains path separators.

Thus, your command line would start like this:

```
perl -S variant_effect_predictor.pl -custom C0066PH1.H3...
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly setup your environment your should use .bashrc not .profile

If you have a .bashrc file (most modern distros are using .bashrc by default now) most likely there is a IF statement in the .profile file that will check for the existence of the .bashrc file and will not process the .profile file any further when a .bashrc file is found.

Contents of a typical .profile file with the "check for .bashrc" IF statement

snip from a .profile file...

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # include .bashrc if it exists
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
fi
```

In the .bashrc file add this line to add additional entries to your PATH variable

```
$ PATH="$PATH:user_path_1:user_path_2:user_path_3"
```

$PATH will keep the existing path variable and to add other paths just use the colon [:] before each additional path.

Alternatively you can use multiple .bashrc files to fit any environment setup you need. Just create a file and name it with another name .bash_other_rc and then call it from the command line like so...

```
$ bash -f .bash_other_rc
```

That will start a bash session with the variables, aliases, etc you need for that session.